# Unityアプリでスクリーンキャプチャした画像が、iOS機種によって挙動がことなる

Tags: ios, unity3d

Unityで作成中のアプリ内に、スクリーンショットを保存する機能を実装しています。
スクリーンショットは、以下の流れで作成しています。

1.　Texture2D.ReadPixels() & Apply()で、読込&テクスチャを生成。
2.　EncodeToPNG()で、byteデータを取得。
3.　2で取得したbyteデータをファイルに書き込み。

画像ファイルは生成できているのですが、
iOSの機種？によって、挙動が異なる状況に遭遇しました。

具体例：
　・iPhone6で正常の向きの場合、iPhone5では上下が逆になる。

・上下を反転させる処理を組み込んだ場合、
　 iPhone6で逆向きになり、iPhone5では、正常の向きになる。

サードパーティのライブラリ等は利用しておらず、UnityのAPIのみです。
また、アプリ内で、機種による分岐処理は含んでいないため、何が原因なのかがわからない状況です。

問題を引き起こしている原因、または解決方法等などを教えていただけないでしょうか？

動作環境
・Unity 5.3.4  (ただし、記憶にあるかぎり、実装当初（2015/11頃)のバージョンから発生済）
・Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

※原因がわかりましたので、自己回答です。

不具合ではなく、Unityの仕様でした。
http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/SL-PlatformDifferences.html

Build Settingsで、"Auto Graphics API"が有効だったため、
実機に出力した際は、
　iPhone6 - Metal
　iPhone5s - OpengGLES 
という異なる動作になり、報告した状況が発生していました。

"Auto Graphics API"のチェックを外して、
OpenGLES3
OpenGLES2
を指定することで、現象が発生しなくなることを確認、対応できました。